# Sum with list switching

Tags: list-manipulation

It is a question that can be answered through comments, but if anyone has a more practical idea it will be welcome.

The question is: How to merge the sum using $p1$ and $p2$ in a more practical way in this my example?

```
origin = {0, 0, 0}; p1 = {54, 55, 0}; p2 = {55, 54, 0}; tam = {60, 60,
   60};
list = {origin, origin + p1, origin + p1 + p2, origin + p1 + p2 + p1, 
   origin + p1 + p2 + p1 + p2};
tam = {tam, tam + p1, tam + p1 + p2, tam + p1 + p2 + p1, 
   tam + p1 + p2 + p1 + p2};

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick],
  Yellow, Cuboid[list[[1]], tam[[1]]],
  Blue, Cuboid[list[[2]], tam[[2]]],
  Yellow, Cuboid[list[[3]], tam[[3]]],
  Blue, Cuboid[list[[4]], tam[[4]]],
  Yellow, Cuboid[list[[5]], tam[[5]]]},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `FoldList[Plus, origin, {p1, p2, p1, p2}]` or to automate the duplicity of the list (but reduce clarity and increase code length) `FoldList[Plus, origin, Join @@ ConstantArray[{p1, p2}, 2]]`

Comment: You're looking for `Accumulate @ {origin, p1, p2, p1, p2}`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I liked the idea of `Join @@ ConstantArray[{p1, p2}, 2]]`, because I can control the number of repetitions through the second parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Mathematica offers a lot of ways to apply this coding principle. Here is one way to apply it your code.

```
origin = {0, 0, 0}; 
p1 = {54, 55, 0}; 
p2 = {55, 54, 0}; 
tam = {60, 60,  60};
offsets = {p1, p2, p1, p2};
list1 = FoldList[Plus, origin, offsets];
list2 = FoldList[Plus, tam, offsets];
colors = PadRight[{}, 5, {Yellow, Blue}];

Graphics3D[
  MapThread[{#1, Cuboid[#2, #3]} &, {colors, list1, list2}], 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: boxes]

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `FoldList[Plus, ...]` over `Accumulate`? The latter seems to be more than 10 times faster, and is imho more readable.

Comment: @MartinEnder. Speed is hardly a consideration it this case. My goal is reduce repetitive typing.

Comment: Ah I see, `FoldList[Plus, ...]` let's you extract the initial element. I guess you could do that with `Accumulate` with something like `Accumulate[offsets ~Prepend~ origin]`. I guess at that point they look equally inelegant.

Comment: @MartinEnder. Right. And `Prepend` will likely annihilate the speed advantage of `Accumulate` over such a short list.

Comment: sorry, the comment regarding efficiency wasn't about being faster in this case but getting into the habit of using the generally more efficient function.

Comment: @MartinEnder. That's not a habit I want to acquire. It is better to use the most appropriate function for the job than the most efficient. In many cases, when expressions will not be evaluated many times, considerations such as maintainability or clarity should override concern for efficiency. Why write obscure code just to save a millisecond or two?

Comment: The premise of my first comment was that `FoldList[Plus, ...]` had no readability or maintainability benefit over `Accumulate`. I was under the assumption that they are equally valid options in this case, but `Accumulate` would be the generally preferrable solution when applying the same function to more data.